# Plug in for Protege to Create/Edit SPIN Constraints and Constructors?

Tags: sparql, protege, spin-rdf

Is there a plug-in or other means to create and edit SPARQL/SPIN constraints and constructors in Protege?

As I understand it, to capture SPIN constraints in RDF, the SPARQL code for the ASK or CONSTRUCT queries needs to be parsed and encoded.  It's not stored as an opaque string.  Therefore, it would seem that some plugin with knowledge of SPARQL and SPIN would be required.

I've loaded RDF from Topbraid Composer including SPIN constraints into Protege 4.3.0, and it seems to see the constraints as annotations, but I cannot seem to find all of the details, critically including all of the underlying SPARQL code.  I do see it when text editing the RDF file.

In the broad sense, I'm trying to find a way to create/edit SPIN constraints and constructors and load them into Sesame to have them operate on individuals instantiated from my classes.  I posted another question about the path from TopBraid Composer into Sesame.  I'm trying to keep my questions more specific since I'm a newbie on Stack Overflow.

BTW, no I don't want to use SWRL instead.  I've had trouble expressing the constraints I need using SWRL.  I've had success using SPARQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No, there isn't -  as far as I know. For editing there is the Topbraid Composer as you already know.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I just need to get the classes, properties, constructors and constraints from TopBraid Composer into Sesame, which is another question I've already posted.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions TopBraid Composer will store SPIN constraints in RDF by default.  Given that the query is stored as RDF triples, there should be no problem storing them in any RDF data store.  Applying the SPIN constraints is a different issue, as the system will need to know how to interpret the queries for different SPIN properties.

Are you certain you cannot "see" them in Protégé or Sesame?  The constraints are defined on the class using the property `spin:constraint` and should appear as a bnode.  Make sure you also import http://spinrdf.org/spin, or at least define a property named `spin:constraint`.  In the very least, the following should always work to find your constraints:

```
SELECT ?constraint ?class
WHERE {
   ?class <http://spinrdf.org/spin#constraint> ?constraint
}
```

...where `?constraint` is bound to a bnode representing the constraint in RDF and `?class` is the class the constraint is defined for.

Also, if you would rather store the constraints as SPARQL strings, see Preferences > TopBraid Composer > SPIN and check one of the boxes in "Generate sp:text...".  Then you can get the query text via the following query:

```
SELECT ?query ?class
WHERE {
   ?class <http://spinrdf.org/spin#constraint> ?constraint .
   ?constraint <http://spinrdf.org/sp#text> ?query
}
```

Comment: Thanks @scotthenninger.  It turns out that I no longer need Protege to edit my SPIN constraints because I can now edit using TopBraid Composer Free edition and load the resulting RDF into Sesame.  The key to that was to make sure the RDF file was loaded into the default graph, which is not the default loading method in Sesame workbench Add command.  So now I have a means to edit and exercise SPIN constraints, constructors and rules.